# Create toggle menu using Polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm trying to create a toggle menu with Polymer.
What I want is plain simple, when I click an item I want to display only the related div as the content.
I'm using the core-scalffold element which gives you a menu and a content layout.

Which should be the best approach to accomplish this using polymer components and events?

```
 <core-scaffold>
  <core-header-panel navigation flex>
    <core-toolbar id="navheader">
    </core-toolbar>
    <core-menu>
      <core-item label="Content 1"></core-item>
      <core-item label="Content 2"></core-item>
    </core-menu>
  </core-header-panel>

  <span tool>Title</span>

  <div class="content1">
      Hi there content1!
  </div>
   <div class="content2">
      Hi there content2!
  </div>
</core-scaffold>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `core-pages` element provides a way of making selectable sections, so this is a good choice for the content divs. Then, since `core-menu` and the `core-pages` both have `selected` properties, it's easy to bind the two elements together. To use Polymer data-binding, we have to use a template. If we put the whole thing in an auto-binding template we get something like this:

```
<template is="auto-binding">

  <core-scaffold>

    <core-header-panel navigation flex>
      <core-toolbar id="navheader">
      </core-toolbar>
      <core-menu selected="0" selectedIndex="{{selected}}">
        <core-item label="Content 1"></core-item>
        <core-item label="Content 2"></core-item>
      </core-menu>
    </core-header-panel>

    <span tool>Title {{selected}}</span>

    <core-pages selected="{{selected}}">
      <div class="content1">
          Hi there content1!
      </div>
      <div class="content2">
          Hi there content2!
      </div>
    </core-pages>

  </core-scaffold>

</template>
```

Note: I bound `selectedIndex` property of `core-menu` so I could use `selected` for setting the default.

http://jsbin.com/wivec/1/edit

If you really want a solution that uses events instead of binding, let me know.

Comment: I'd love to see that solution that uses events, Scott.